# Taking all javascript from html to page-specific js file

Tags: django

What bit bothers me about django, is that I see in many examples that raw javascript is included in html with `<script>` tag. I would like to have it in independent files which are included in every page in `<head>` tag so that html stays clean. So that I will call something like {% add_jscript %}some js code{% endaddjsscript %} anywhere in the template to add js code. After all processing when the page is generated and it will dynamically collects all portions of added js code from processed templates and serve it as one js file.

Some app already does this or am I forced to do this on my own ?

Comment: Are you talking about `<script>` tag? Can js be included in html without `<script?` tag?

Comment: That's the way I do not do it, because you are mixing html and javascript. I want to maximize 'unobtrusiveness' of javascript.

Comment: Js can be loaded separetely from html. It's a great technique , because browsers can cache this js file. Isn't that enough for you?

Comment: And if you want to use variables of current context ? :)

Comment: Ah, I got it. Sorry, I have not seen such an app

Answer (score 0):

I use django-sekizai (https://github.com/ojii/django-sekizai/) for this kind of thing. If I understand you correctly, I believe that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to the party, but another option you could try (shameless plug) is a django app i've been working on which will allow you to inject django variables directly into external javascript files, a la Require.js

[django-js-variable-injector](https://github.com/steinbachr/django-js-variable-injector)